# My solution seems "Ugly"

Tags: javascript, node.js

After a lot of tinkering and searching  i am able to get this code tonwork. However it feels dirty and I had to go through a lot of trouble because node doesn't like to pass data to global variables, is there a better way to write this? I am very new to node so I feel like I missing pieces that would have made my life much easier. As per @JordanHendrix suggestion I will be moving over to template literals.

```
var wikipedia = require("node-wikipedia");
var infobox = require('wiki-infobox');
var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;

var fs = require('fs');

String.prototype.format = function()
{
   var content = this;
   for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++)
   {
        var replacement = '{' + i + '}';
        content = content.replace(replacement, arguments[i]);
   }
   return content;
};


function getLinks() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    wikipedia.page.data("List_of_hip_hop_musicians", { content: true }, function(response) {
      fs.writeFile("response.json", JSON.stringify(response, null, 2), function(err) {
        if(err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
      });
      resolve(response.links);
    });
  });
}


function getInfo(links){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.appendFile("info.csv", "name, background, birth_name, birth_date, birth_place, origin, genre, occupation, instrument, years_active, label, website\n", function(err) {
      if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
    });
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
      var link = links[i]['*'];
      resolveInfo(link).then(function(newText){
        fs.appendFile("info.csv", newText, function(err) {
          if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
          }
        });
      });
    }
    resolve(text)
  });
}


function resolveInfo(link) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    infobox(link, 'en', function(err, data){
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      try {
        var text = '{0}, {1}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}\n'.format(data.name.value, data.background.value, data.birth_name.value, data.birth_date.value, JSON.stringify(data.birth_place), data.origin.value, data.genre.text, JSON.stringify(data.occupation), data.instrument.text, data.years_active.value, data.label.value, data.website.value);
      } catch(err){
        var text = "";
      }
      resolve(text);
    });
  });
}


getLinks().then(function(links) {
  getInfo(links).then(function(text){
  });
});
```

Comment: why not just use template literals here, if you dont know what they are google 'es6 template literals'

Comment: @JordanHendrix probs because I've never heard of the term today. I literally just started typing in node hours ago. I'm coming from a heavy Python and Go background. Though I just googled it and while that seems to be a nice replacement for the String Prototype it doesn't help with the actually problem, where on line 66 console.log(text) i'm not seeing the data I expect.

Comment: ok cool, yea I thought you might not know, takes a look, it will make sense!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @JordanHendrix good to know though i'll be swapping that in.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a good medium for back and forth question modification. Please edit the question to be as specific as possible, or close it.

Comment: you could have given a better title :)

Comment: Lol @user1645290 ... I sat there and I thought about it.. and I looked at the code over and over and I kept saying to myself... that's just ugly lmao. I literally decided to write my first stuff in node today because I'm using electron for a project, but I normally write in Python or Go. So looking at the node code I wrote (which took too long), I just feel  unsatisfied by it.

Comment: In function `getInfo` you returned a value to a promise by `resolve(text)`. Where does that variable `text` come from?

Comment: The plan was the resolve the text and write a file vs appending to a file. So where I'm appending I was building a  text object, text += newText; but because of callback scope I wasn't able to pass that information into a global variable which I can then use later to write the file. For example If this were python. Text = "", for line in some data, text += line, write(text). What was happening was that the header would write, but text would resolve empty because none of the appends to text kept... so in my mind this is hacky. I should be able to point to a variable in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider a few things. First: use arrow functions whenever possible, makes you code to look much cleaner.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  //...
});
```

You might wanna have a look into [promisification](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html) to further cleanup. You would need to use bluebirds promise library though (which i'd recommend anyway).

```
var fs = require("fs");
Promise.promisifyAll(fs);
fs.readFileAsync("file.js", "utf8").then(...)
```

Last but not least, chain your promises properly:

```
getLinks()
  .then(getInfo)
  .then(text => console.log(text));
```

Comment: Awesome let me get to work on these suggestions, thanks.